# How to make Cydia Tweak for GPS location updates

Tags: ios7, xcode5, jailbreak, cydia, cydia-substrate

I want to make a Cydia Tweak that could get device location updates. I tried **CLLocationManager** but it does nothing. Although I have loaded my Tweak in SpringBoard.

I m using Xcode 5 with iOS 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any update on this? I'm also looking for the same